# Is BeginAcceptTcpClient thread safe? C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, tcp

I´m starting in the world of `TCP Asynchronous` servers, searching a way to handle several connections at the same time I found out that `BeginAcceptTcpClient` could be a solution.

I´ve found two possible ways to use `BeginAcceptTcpClient` at the start of the server to receive connections. My question would be: what´s the difference between those two and which one would be thread safe (or if both are).

**FIRST WAY**

Calling `BeginAcceptTcpClient` inside the callback.

```
static TcpListener socket = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 4444);

public static void InitNetwork()
        {
            socket.Start();
            socket.BeginAcceptTcpClient(new AsyncCallback(OnClientConnect), null);
        }

private static void OnClientConnect(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            TcpClient newclient = socket.EndAcceptTcpClient(ar);
            socket.BeginAcceptTcpClient(new AsyncCallback (OnClientConnect), null); // Call the Callback again to continue listening

            HandleClient.CreateConnection(newclient); //Do stuff with the client recieved
        }
```

**SECOND WAY**

Using `AutoResetEvent`.

```
static TcpListener socket = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 4444);
private AutoResetEvent connectionWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);

public static void InitNetwork()
        {
            socket.Start();

            while(true)
            {
              socket.BeginAcceptTcpClient(new AsyncCallback(OnClientConnect), null);
              connectionWaitHandle.WaitOne(); // Wait until a client has begun handling an event
              connectionWaitHandle.Reset(); // Reset wait handle or the loop goes as fast as it can (after first request)
            }

        }

private static void OnClientConnect(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            TcpClient newclient = socket.EndAcceptTcpClient(ar);
            connectionWaitHandle.Set(); //Inform the main thread this connection is now handled

            HandleClient.CreateConnection(newclient);  //Do stuff with the client recieved
        }
```

I´m searching the correct way to handle multiple connections (been thread safe). I appreciate any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer `AcceptTcpClientAsync`. It's simpler than `BeginAcceptTcpClient` and still asynchronous.

```
public async Task InitNetwork()
{
    while( true )
    {
        TcpClient newclient = await socket.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
        Task.Run( () => HandleClient.CreateConnection( newclient ) );
    }
}
```

Internally, `AcceptTcpClientAsync` use `Task.Factory.FromAsync` to wrap `BeginAcceptTcpClient` and `EndAcceptTcpClient` into a Task object.

```
public Task<TcpClient> AcceptTcpClientAsync()
{
    return Task<TcpClient>.Factory.FromAsync(BeginAcceptTcpClient, EndAcceptTcpClient, null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. Is AcceptTcpClientAsync thread safe? What happens if two clients connect at the same time? I search and see that some use "if (task.IsFaulted) /  task.Wait();" after AcceptTcpClientAsync. Thank you again.

Comment: I use this method in my project to manage multiple clients in multi-thread environment in one of my project and it works fine. Prevent using task.Wait or other synchronous method of task in asynchronous environment, if you want to catch exception, you can simply use try-catch around `await AcceptTcpClientAsync `.

Comment: How to use Task class and async-await is a big topic. If you're interesting in how these things work or how to use them correctly, google async-await or task parallel library

Comment: Should `await` be before `Task.Run` ? I google it and found the two ways. Shows me this correction in the code: [link] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/error-messages/because-this-call-is-not-awaited-the-current-method-continues-to-run)

Comment: Use await if you want to wait until the task is finished. I guess `CreateConnection` should be fire&forget so I didn't use await